# How to render multiple views using in react native?

Tags: react-native

I've managed to build a selection screen using auto complete, basically what I want to do is have a item to be selected, the amount of this item to be updated to the desired amount, and if you wish to add more items to the list there is a button to create a new field (autocomplete + desired amount), the code is the following (but it won't work, I'm showing how I think this should be managed)

```
render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const itemData = this.state.items;
    let mapArray = this.state.amount.slice();
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.autocompleteContainer}>
                {
                    mapArray.map((l, i) => (
                        <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center' }} key={i}>
                            <Autocomplete style={styles.barStyle} data={this.state.query.length > 0 ? (this.state.itemPress ? [] : this.filterData(this.state.query, itemData)) : []}
                                defaultValue={query}
                                placeholder="Digite um item"
                                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text, itemPress: false })}
                                renderItem={item => (
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item, itemPress: true })}>
                                        <Text>{item}</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )} key={i}/>
                            <View>
                                <View style={styles.amount}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} onPress={() => {
                                        var clonedAmountArray = this.state.amount.slice();
                                        clonedAmountArray[i] -= 1;
                                        this.setState({ amount: clonedAmountArray })
                                    }}>
                                        <View>
                                            <Icon style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} name="ios-remove" />
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, alignSelf: 'center', marginLeft: 5 }}>{this.state.amount[i]}</Text>
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 10 }} onPress={() => {
                                        let clonedAmountArray = this.state.amount.slice();
                                        clonedAmountArray[i] += 1;
                                        this.setState({ amount: clonedAmountArray })
                                    }}>
                                        <View>
                                            <Icon style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} name="ios-add" />
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    ))}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    var updatedAmountArray = this.state.amount.slice();
                    updatedAmountArray.push(0);
                    this.setState({ amount: updatedAmountArray, totalViews: this.state.totalViews + 1 })
                }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey', width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 5, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                    <View>
                        <Icon style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} name="ios-add" />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

What I want is to render multiple fields (autocomplete + amount picker) according to the amount of times the "+" bottom buttom has been pressed, also I need to keep records of all the items and amount.

I'm probably doing this wrong in so many ways, I'm still learning react-native and doing lot of things wrong. If you have any suggestion on a easier way to this I would appreciate.

--EDIT--
Thanks to @Mohammed Ashfaq its working the new fields, but it keeps the same value for Autocomplete in all the views:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OnPress function Add1 is to make more fields (autocomplete + amount select).

   ```
   onPress={() => {
     let clonedAmountArray = this.state.amount.slice();
     clonedAmountArray.push(0);
     this.setState({ amount:clonedAmountArray , totalViews: clonedAmountArray.length}) 
   }
   ```
2. OnPress function for Add2 to increase the amount value of a specific index.

   ```
   onPress={() => {
     let clonedAmountArray = this.state.amount.slice();
     clonedAmountArray[i] += 1; 
     this.setState({ amount : clonedAmountArray}) 
   }
   ```
3. OnPress function for Minus icon  to decrease the amount value of a specific index.

   ```
   onPress={() => {
     var clonedAmountArray = this.state.amount.slice();
     clonedAmountArray[i] -= 1; 
     this.setState({ amount : clonedAmountArray}) 
   }
   ```

Comment: there is probably a lot more missing, this is not adding another view, also, how I'm supposed to update each index of "this.setState({ amount: this.state.amount[i] + 1 })"

Comment: There are two + icon in the image one in bottom{Add1} and another on the right side of  Autocomplete component {Add2}  along with - minus Icon. Can you explain what functionality you want to perform with Add1 and Add2?

Comment: Add1 is to make more fields (autocomplete + amount select), Add2 and Minus are for amount select, they should update the this.state.amount[X] where X is the index for that field's amount.

Comment: Please check the updated answer:   1.) Replaced the splice() method with slice(). 2.) Added Two more functions to increase and decrease the value of amount.

Comment: Its working, but the new views have the same value altogether, even if I set key={i}, how could I fix it? (I edited the anwser)

Comment: From your code I am not able to figure out : (1). How you are getting the item value (2 ) what this code  is doing   data={this.state.query.length > 0 ? (this.state.itemPress ? [] : this.filterData(this.state.query, itemData)) : []} (3) which react native package you using for Autocomplete componnet.

Comment: (1). Since its autocomplete, once the user clicks the autocompleted option, the value appears into the field. (2). If the input has characters and no items has been pressed, it will show the autocomplete list available for that input, else it will show a empty list. (3). 'react-native-autocomplete-input'